# google firebase cli listing existing project fails

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I am trying to host my test app on ***firebase*** but every time I input ***firebase init hosting***
and I choose to use an existing project this comes out on the terminal :

error failed to list firebase projects see firebase-debug.log

so I did and what I found was this

```
[debug] [2021-03-18T11:42:55.667Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects pageSize=100
[debug] [2021-03-18T11:42:56.064Z] Failed to make request: invalid json response body at https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects?pageSize=100 reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
[debug] [2021-03-18T11:42:56.364Z] FirebaseError: Failed to make request: invalid json response body at https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects?pageSize=100 reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Client.request (C:\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\apiv2.js:109:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[error] 
[error] Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

so I've checked that I am logged in and that my project exists I also tried
`firebase login --reauth`
but I still get the same error what should I do?

Comment: And have you checked what the `firebase-debug.log` file says? can you share it?